# How do I change the array value?

Tags: php

Is it possible to change the highlighted word to numbers without changing it in database table?

wanted from this

```
$value['how']
```

to this

```
$value['0']
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your DB query?

Comment: Direct approach - `$value['0']=$value['how']` - _unclear of what you are asking_

Comment: How did you get those values? Please post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/function.array-values)

```
$array = array("how" => "how-value", "to" => "to-value");
print_r(array_values($array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => how-value
    [1] => to-value
)
```

**EDIT BY OP**

To get the value

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $someArray = array_values($value);
 print_r($someArray[0]);
}

//return 144
```

Comment: yup this is exactly what i wanted, thank u very much!

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: now im stuck at getting the "how value" using the array_values()

Comment: Stuck as in? You need to explain the problem.

Comment: How do i retrieve the "how" value using array_values. This code doesn't get "144" value (print_r(array_values($array[0])))

Comment: Please update your question with code snippet as it is difficult to understand here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151570/discussion-between-milan-chheda-and-begineeeerrrr).

Comment: im sorry to revive this question back, but array_values did not permanently change the key value...how to make it permanently?

Answer (score 1):

@Milan Chheda answer is correct but I am just briefing here so the user can get a better idea of that.

Use array_values() to get the values of an array.

```
$FormedArray = array_values($your_array);
```

now print that array `print_r($FormedArray);`

You will get your result like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 144
    [1] => 41
    [2] => USA
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 12
)
```

Here is a working example. https://eval.in/843720

Comment: so how do i output the 144?

Comment: yes i did, it work perfectly, just that i wanted to get the 144 using the array_values. because in the future, i wanted to get the value easier using count++

Comment: Yes, that's what you got in for each loop. And it's better to use array_values before you implement that array. Because In that loop you will get array values as one element not by an array and array_values takes an array as it's argument.